# In the getArray method, the resulting array is always empty

Tags: java, arrays, file, methods, parameters

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundxception {
    File usdCoins = new File("C:\\Users\\saif9\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\USD coins.txt");
    getArray(usdCoins);
}

public static void getArray (File coins) {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(coins);
        int counter = 0;
        while (reader.hasNextDouble()) {
             System.out.print(reader.nextDouble() + " / ");
             System.out.println(counter);
             counter++;
        }

        double jodCoins[] = new double[counter];
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.hasNextDouble()) {
             jodCoins [i] = reader.nextDouble();
             i++;
             for (int j= 0; j < i; j++) {
                 System.out.println(jodCoins[j]);
             } 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ????
    }
```

Comment: Your path is not correct. `C:\Users\saif9\OneDrive\Desktop\USD coins.txt` should be `C:\\Users\\saif9\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\USD coins.txt` ***or*** `C:/Users/saif9/OneDrive/Desktop/USD coins.txt` -- the ``\`` is a special character.

Comment: You're reading from the scanner until `hesNextDouble()` is false, and then you're doing it all again. `hasNextDouble()` won't magically start returning `true` again after it has returned `false`. You should only use one loop here, not two.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-initialise the reader ,after the first while , the reader dont have more double to read , so you need to assign it again to a new Scanner (entries are not clear here if you need to reuse the same data of coins file ) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundxception {
    File usdCoins = new File("C:\\Users\\saif9\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\USD coins.txt");
    getArray(usdCoins);
}

public static void getArray (File coins) {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(coins);
        int counter = 0;
        while (reader.hasNextDouble()) {
             System.out.print(reader.nextDouble() + " / ");
             System.out.println(counter);
             counter++;
        }

        double jodCoins[] = new double[counter];
        int i = 0;

        // re-initialise the reader here :
        reader = new Scanner(coins);

        while (reader.hasNextDouble()) {
             jodCoins [i] = reader.nextDouble();
             i++;
             for (int j= 0; j < i; j++) {
                 System.out.println(jodCoins[j]);
             } 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ????
    }
```